# CURDATE functionality from db2 query

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I'm trying to apply 'curdate()' functionality to a select statement from DB2. I'm used to MySQL but I'm still trying to get the hang of a lot of the DB2 functionality and how to essentially marry the two.

My query is complete except for one line. I'm trying to select based on a ship date, which is the column `EXTD1H` and I need to check it against today or curdate(). The problem is that column in DB2 is an integer format, not a date format, and I don't have the option of changing it. In prior inserts to mysql, I've been able to put it into Y-m-d format and I know I can trim the year using LEFT(EXTD1H, 4) but I have no idea how to modify my select so that I can say `WHERE EXTD1H is today` so that I'm only selecting records for this date.

Here's the query:

```
select 
  invnoz as ORDER,
  fstatz as STATUS 
from gportafl
  /*where EXTD1H is curdate, hypothetically*/ 
  AND FSTATZ <> 'S'
  limit 20;
```

As you can see, I have a commented line where my issue is. I'm sure it's simple I just can't seem to find in the documentation exactly what I'm looking for, which is to be able to use that INT column to verify that selected records are from today.

UPDATE:

All values from the column are in YYYYMMDD format i.e.
`20180202`
but it should be `2018-02-02`

Comment: Show an example of an integer-value in the EXTD1H column and its matching calendar-date, i.e. is it YYYYMMDD always in digits, with leading zeroes on the MM and YY as necessary?

Comment: How exactly is `DATE` represented as `INT`?

Comment: I just updated with the values. Basically, the column "represents" dates but it is a standard character column, in this case it is an INT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best not to do operations on the columns, so the indexes are used.
You can typecast the current date to fit your data as follows:

```
WHERE extd1h = INTEGER(VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT DATE,'YYYYMMDD'))
```